# Why can console of neo4j be started with the jar file in the directory Neo4j CE 3.1.1/bin/, but not Neo4j CE 3.1.1/bin/neo4j-ce.exe?

Tags: neo4j

It used to be able to start with "Neo4j CE 3.1.1/bin/neo4j-ce.exe". Today, it suddenly does not work with the exe file anymore, after I put the jar file from this website https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/3.1.0.3 to the directory "Neo4j CE 3.1.1/plugins". (The plugin does not work either.)

Comment: Can you try to force kill neo4j or restart your computer and try again, also try checking the neo4j.conf to see whereplugin directory is set

Comment: I just uninstalled and re-installed neo4j multiple times and now the exe file works.

Comment: Where can you find neo4j.conf?

Comment: "Neo4j CE 3.1.1/conf/neo4j.conf" i think

Comment: I don't have a conf folder under Neo4j CE 3.1.1.

Comment: use search in windows for neo4j.conf

Comment: I just did, it can't be found.

Comment: Now the exe file does not work again.

Comment: please download neo4j zip and follow this instructions https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/, exe version has some problems